# How to change font type and size in case of: table/figure caption, page number?

Tags: captions, fontsize, page-numbering

I use packages: fancyhdr and caption.

I want to change font to Arial only in those two cases:
1.table/figure caption
2.page number

Also I want to change sizes to 10pt and 11pt

I know in captionsetup I can use font=small, and some similar for page number eg. fanctheader[CE]{\small \thepage} but it is not enough. And I have no idea how tho change font type.

Comment: Instead of using Arial, which is a not so good clone of Helvetica, use the original `\usepackage{helvet}` which enables `\sffamily` to use Helvetica.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you compile with `XeLaTeX` or `LuaLaTeX`, it's easy to use `arial`:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont{arial}
```

if you want to use arial as the `default` sans font. If you just want to use locally, in captions/headers/footers, you define a font switch with:

```
\newfontfamily\captionfont{arial}
```

If you compile with `pdfLaTeX`, there is no support for arial. However there is an arial clone, named `uarial`, made by URW, for which there *is* a package (same name) which is not part of TeX Live nor MiKTeX. But you can find a ready-to-install on CTAN [here](http://mirror.ctan.org/install/fonts/urw/arial.tds.zip). To use it, you have:

1. unzip it at the root of  a LocalTeXMF directory. If you use TeXLive, you already have one; with MiKTeX you have to create one. DO NOT unzip it in the TeXMF directory of your distribution.
2. Refresh the filenames data base i.e. run texhash (TeX Live) or `Refresh FNDB`(MiKTeX) via MiKTeX Settings.
3. Add to your home updmap.cfg this line: `Map ua1.map`.
4. Run updmap from the command line.

After that, uarial is ready to be used. Ther is a `uarial.sty` package if you want to make it the default sans font. If not, you can define a font switch, e.g.:

\newcommand\captionfont{\fontfamily{ua1}\selectfont}

Other solution: use `helvetica` (from which arial is inspired). There is a `helvet` package that is part of every distribution. For the switch in that case, the LaTeX name of the helvetica family is `phv`.

That being said, you have formatting commands in `caption`. you can say for instance:

```
\DeclareCaptionFont{\captionfont\footnotesize}
```

With `fancyhdr`you similarly can define a new page style with:

```
\fancypagestyle{mystyle}{%
  \captionfont\small…
  \fancyhead[…]{…}
  \fancyfoot[…]{…}
  ..................
   }%
```

then apply it with: `\pagestyle{mystyle}`.